# IntelliJ grayed out Run Configuration

Tags: intellij-idea

Using IntelliJ I have some Run Configurations that are grayed out.

I can still run them but I can't find why they are grayed out.

[image]

Comment: I created a request in their tracker. You can upvote if you want Pycharm to be more explicit: [link](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-43437).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

A dimmed run configuration simply means it hasn't been saved. Technically called "temporary run configurations" by the IntelliJ manual:

> Temporary configurations are marked with semi-transparent icons and are managed same way as the permanent configurations. By default, 5 temporary configurations are allowed per project. You can change this limit via the Edit Configurations dialog.

Saving (which makes the config permanent) can be done in either the "Run/Debug Configurations" menu (visible only when selected), or in the config selection dropdown in the general UI:

[image: save locations]

After saving, the configuration will move up to group with the reset of the saved configurations and will no longer be dimmed. As far as I can tell, you can have as many saved configs that you want.

Comment: It didn't work for me, even after I saved the configuration and it appeared at the top of other configurations. Luckily I can still run the app via "Run..." button (Alt + Shift + F10). Still can't find an answer for the original issue.

Comment: Another solution for this issue is discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61034413/2185783

Answer (score -2):

To fix this:

- Go to your project directory
- Select a folder -> New -> Java Class -> Filename.java
- Go to add configuration
- Fill these fields like in the image:

[image]