# Run button is greyed out - intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I was working on a project in Intellij then suddenly there was a pop up and now the run button is greyed out. It is a Java FX project and it runs with coverage and debug, but the normal run button is greyed out. What could be the problem?

PS: I know I don't give you much to work with but unfortunately it was working and now it isn't, that's all.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This has happened to me countless times. One possible problem is that the program is still running in the background and hasn't exited completely. Check your running processes for java applications and see if it exists.

Comment: Or a variation - close Intellij window and reopen. That worked for me based on this tip.

Answer (score 43):

I had the same issue and fixed it with the old "Invalidate Caches and Restart"

Comment: I was on 2020.3.1 community edition. The Java class (has some recursion methods) that I wrote had some weird behavior already. The results were not what I have expected. I verified the method by hand and it should be correct. Then I updated IDE to 2020.3.2, the project won't run. Some configurations became "unknown". Then I removed those configurations and "Invalidate Caches and Restart" from "File" menu, re-compile re-run the project, problem solved. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me too :d

Comment: This worked for me when I checked 'clear file system caches and local history' as well but not otherwise

Answer (score 20):

Open the source code, right-click and hit run using the option run "filename.java".

IntelliJ will make the configuration for you and then you can click the run button after the configuration is made by the IDE.

Same thing for debug configuration.

Comment: I do not see this option in IntelliJ Ideal 2021.3.3

Comment: I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.3 (Community Edition), and i can see this option. I would suggest you @AndrewS to check again.

Answer (score 3):

Try to start the program again via <kbd>Run</kbd> in the menu bar.

Comment: This worked for me, I can run the app via "Run..." button (Alt + Shift + F10). Still can't find an answer for the original issue.

Comment: It looks like the program was still running in the background as explained in @Jason's answer

Comment: Thanks, at first I thought restarting IntelliJ could solve the issue but it didn't. Today I try again and also make sure that no Java program is running in the background, then it work as expected. I'm not sure if it related to Grable build or not, but I always have this issue with Gradle project.

Answer (score 3):

Restarting IntelliJ and re-opening the project resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> solved my problem.
I guess for me disabling windows instant replay fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Change the jdk version to 11 or any lts ..

Steps :

1. file> Project Structure
2. Edit SDK [enter image description here][1]

Click on the below link to see the image for editing SDK :
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IyXA.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same thing using IDEA 2021.3.3 ultimate edition. My "Run Hello (Shift+F10)" button was greyed out, so I right clicked the source code (any whitespace in the editor worked fine), and there was an option in the menu called "Run Hello.main() (Ctrl+Shift+F10)", which WAS clickable. I clicked it, then it ran, after which the first button was no longer greyed out.

Answer (score 0):

I think it the maven/gradle plugin that failed to load.

For me I closed the project, open another previous project and the run button appeared.Then I closed it and open my new project,I got a prompt bottom right that says  "load maven script" I clicked it and it was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the src/main directory -> Mark Directory as -> Sources Root

This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same issue as I started with freshly installed Intellij. There's a button of `EDIT CONFIGURATIONS` near run button. I added the configurations (just a couple of things) and it worked.

`Add configurations under 'Edit Configuration' there and it should work.`