# Can't run the Spring boot project (no errors just isn't starting)

Tags: android, spring, spring-boot, android-studio, kotlin

I created new project using Spring Initializr and i can't run it.
Here is screenshot:

[IDE - Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYLQK.png)

Also i couldn't find pom.xml file (i've been watching guide and this file was shown there)

UPD:

I tried to invalidate caches and after restarting i've got these errors:

[Errors list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDeiN.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run button is greyed out - intellij](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61034359/run-button-is-greyed-out-intellij)

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos unfortunately, not

Comment: you can't find pom because you selected gradle instead of maven

Comment: @zawarudo uh, i didn't know that, sorry for stupid question