# how to setup intelli J configuration correctly?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, configuration

I was trying to a test file, but run button keeps gray. chatgpt told me to check configuration is correct, but I dont know what is correct.

[image: run button remains gray]

[image: dont know how to setup configuration]

Could anyone please tell me what configuration is and how to set it up correctly?

Comment: Does any of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61034359/5133585) answer your question?

Comment: There's a green run button in the margin.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run button is greyed out - intellij](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61034359/run-button-is-greyed-out-intellij)

Answer (score 0):

Click on the pom.xml file and set it as maven project.
If it is not working, go to: file -->invalidate caches and clear the data.

If you still have an  issue it seems like something related with the index's of your project.

I had a similar issue so I right click on the project folder, and selected:
repair idea

let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Mark your src folder as sources in the folder's context menu.